# GRASS GIS temporal raster individual layer statistical summary

Tags: raster, grass-gis, spatio-temporal-data, grass.script

I have created a temporal raster in GRASS GIS which has 90 layers. I would like to extract the mean of each raster layer and export it as text file. Right now I have to export the rasters as GeoTiffs and stack them in R to calculate the mean. Is there an equivalent function in GRASS to extract mean, sd etc for each raster layer in a GRASS GIS time-space raster?

Comment: I am not sure if I got it, but do you need something like r.series ? Using r.series you can add multiple layers and use some functions like mean,mode etc. Another option is the r.report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRASS GIS has made it very easy to calculate both spatial as well as temporal descriptive statistical summaries. To get the statistical summaries such as mean, median, standard deviation etc. for each raster layer saved within GRASS `t.ras` one can use `t.rast.univar`
This function creates statistical summaries for each of the layer. By checking the advance option one can also get median and quantile values. The output can be saved as a text file and can be used for further analysis in excel, R etc. 
[Here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/t.rast.univar.html) is a good reference for this function.

Comment: In addition, see also https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Temporal_data_processing